# Downgrade SUSE SP3 to SP2

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sap, suse, sles

@Community! is there a way anyone can move from SUSE for SAP SP3 to SP2 without losing the existing setup and configuration in GCP VM instance.

**High level overview**

We have a security endpoint that requires SUSE Kernel `5.3.18-24.78.1` and as per SUSE documentation [List of SUSE Linux version](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000019587), this kernel version is only available in SP2 so, we're unable to use since we're using SP3.

**Question**

I do not have any backup in SP2 to restore to, and I do not want to rebuild the server to SP2 since I ran the risk of doing a full reconfiguration of the system. So for a VM instance in GCP, does anyone know how I can revert the SUSE version from SP3 to SP2 without losing all my configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no supporting document on GCP regarding downgrading from a higher version of OS to lower version. GCP had a list of Google provided public-images that you can use and are supported by Google.

Based on your statement, your security endpoint's needed kernel version in SLES 15 SP2. What you can try to do is parallel installation of multiple kernels in [SUSE Linux Enterprise Server](https://documentation.suse.com/sles/15-SP1/html/SLES-all/cha-tuning-multikernel.html#sec-tuning-multikernel-enable), SUSE supports installing multiple kernel version. Also, there is also a possibility that there will be re-configuration that will occur when updating or downgrading a kernel.